# Is there any way to return input() in python if user enters backspace?

Tags: python, input

Is there any way to return the user's input after pressing backspace in python rather than just enter key?
I know how to get user's input by using text = input("> ") and using keyboard.is_pressed('\b') to check if user enters backspace using keyboard module. But I wanted to check that while user is typing. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: return input ? i didnt understand that part?

Comment: I meant the string that input() returns after you type your input. @SandrinJoy

Comment: so if i input liike "asbsjd" and when press a space , you need the output asbsjd?

Comment: Something like that but instead of space its backspace. So if user inputs "abcd" and a backspace, i need "abcd" instead of deleting 'd'. @SandrinJoy

Comment: ok , Understood. i have posted my solution

Answer (score 1):

**`msvcrt` library works for me**

*PS : I use windows OS*

```
import msvcrt
x="hehe"
data=""
while x!="\b":
    x=msvcrt.getch()
    x=x.decode("utf-8")
    data+=x
print("Gotcha !",data)
```